# Javascript/HTML How do I change something that's in JOT format to GIF format

Tags: javascript, image-manipulation

I have an application that generates signatures.  It is in JOT format:
http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/CodeDoc/JOT/JOT/GD.html

How do I write a JavaScript function to convert it into GIF format.

I have been given this C example, but I don't know how to convert it.

Thanks.

```
void doJot2Gif(PODSObject *podsObj,const char* pBase64Data,const char* pFilename)
{
 int len = (int)(strlen(pBase64Data));

 if ( len > 0 ) {

  // make a copy of the JOT data 
  unsigned char* ptrBuff = (unsigned char*)malloc(len+1);
  memset(ptrBuff,0,len+1);
  strcpy((char*)ptrBuff,pBase64Data);

  // append the GIF extension to the filename
  char gif_filepath[256];
  strcpy(gif_filepath,pFilename);
  strcat(gif_filepath,".GIF");
  HANDLE  hFile = FILE_OPEN((char*)gif_filepath);

  if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
   return;
  }

  // call the routine that converts the JOT to the GIF and writes the file
  jottogif((unsigned char*)ptrBuff, hFile);

  free(ptrBuff);
  FILE_CLOSE(hFile);

 }

}
```

Comment: You can't just do a mapping from C to JavaScript when you're working at this level. They're designed for entirely different things.

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, all the interesting stuff happens here:

```
// call the routine that converts the JOT to the GIF and writes the file
jottogif((unsigned char*)ptrBuff, hFile);
```

The actual conversion is done by this `jottogif` method. The rest of your code example is almost irrelevant, just opening files etc. but not manipulating the image.

This isn't really something JavaScript is well suited for doing. I'd create a webservice to handle the conversion.  The JavaScript then sends the JOT file to the webservice and gets the GIF file as a response.

The webservice could invoke any existing tools/libraries that are available for this conversion.

Comment: I'll look at using another method to get the file GIFed unless someone can think of an easy way to convert.  Shame it uses such an odd format.